# New symfony plugin: PEAR parsing error

Tags: php, plugins, symfony1, pear

When I try to upload a PEAR package for a new plugin to the symfony plugins site, I receive the error

> An error occured while parsing 
>   ynWidgetAjaxAutocompletePlugin-0.1.0b1.tgz
>   (The archive 
>   "ynWidgetAjaxAutocompletePlugin-0.1.0b1.tgz"
>   does not follow PEAR  conventions).

What might be the problem? My `package.xml` validates with `pear package- 
validate`. It is at http://pastebin.com/aeXEG6Y8

**UPDATE**: I've rebuilt the `package.xml` with pfm, but still the same error: http://pastebin.com/R4799KNY

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the `package.xml` is not at the correct place in the tgz archive.

You should package up your package file by using

```
$ pear package
```

because it will put `package.xml` at the right place in the archive.